# Load Places API library from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension to add [Google Maps autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) to Google Calendar's new event location input. I'm trying to load the library in the extension context but it blocks saying `[blocked] The page at domain.com ran insecure content from anotherdomain.com`.

I of course have added `http://anotherdomain.com` to the manfest.json in the "permissions" key. In order to load the actual places library I just downloaded it from `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true`, since i didn't know how to add it directly to the extension.

Comment: Are you using manifest 2.0? If you are using manifest 2.0, you should read http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html . I am not sure if places api is compatible with chrome extension's CSP.

Comment: It seems Places API using `eval` now. It is prohibited by CSP. You either use manifest 1.0 or wait for google fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, it seems it is impossible, so I just used the JSON API and jQuery UI's autocomplete. Here's my trivial implementation https://gist.github.com/3623683